# Pass by reference in Ruby

Tags: ruby, object, reference, enumerator

Apart from passing parameters along with bindings, is there any way to mutate passed objects inside of a block/method to have the changes reflected in the initial objects?

Imagine the requirement is to convert the following:

`{one:1, two:2, three:3, four:4}` into `{one:"1", two:"22", three:"333", four:"4444"}`

I was thinking of something like this:

`{one:1, two:2, three:3, four:4}.each!{ |k,v| v = v.to_s * v }`

Where the changes to the passed variables gets reflected in the actual hash.

I think it *may* be even efficient to have a capability like this? So that the block can directly manupulate those objects without having to create new objects and then assigning it to it.

Somehow feel solving the problem like this involves multiple unnecessary change of object data types and might be inefficient:

`new_hash = Hash[{one:1, two:2, three:3, four:4}.collect{ |k,v| [k, v.to_s * v] }]`

So was wondering, whether there was anything like each! to do it.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you want to accomplish. In your given example, do you want to mutate the original hash, or mutate the values in the hash? Given the former, why not just `collect!` instead of `collect`?

Comment: I was attempting to mutate the values in the hash, but it seems like there is no way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of anything like an `each!`, but this should accomplish what you're trying to do:

```
test = {one:1, two:2, three:3, four:4}

test.each{ |key,val| test[key] = val.to_s * val }

p test

#=> {:one=>"1", :two=>"22", :three=>"333", :four=>"4444"}
```

Comment: Well, I am aware of mutating the original hash like this; but was looking for a generic block (to use as a Proc/Lambda) to do this, thats without having to have dependencies to `test` explicitly in the block.